# Ssh authentication error while deploying using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano

I am trying to deploy my rails application (`Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.4`) through `capistrano` from mac. I have `ssh` keys set up on server. But i keep getting authentication error whenever i try to deploy. The error is:

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xxx: Authentication failed for user deploy@xxx.xxx
```

followed by:

```
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@xxx.xx
```

This is my staging.rb:

```
server "xxx.xx.xxx", user: "deploy", roles: %w{web app db}
set :ssh_options, {
  user: "root",
  forward_agent: false,
  keys: '~/.ssh/id_rsa',
  auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
}
set :branch, "master"
set :rails_env,   "staging"
```

I am able to login to server via terminal using `ssh root@xxx.xx` but cannot login with capistrano. Any help or advice will be appericiated.

Comment: Authentication is failed fo user `deploy@xxx.xx`, not `root@xxx.xx`. Correct first row of the `staging.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

At first. You use two different users in one config. Choice one and edit your staging.rb

Also I am not sure that using public key is a good way. Try to add private key for user Deploy. Then if you able to login as deploy

```
ssh -i id_rsa deploy@xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

try to update gem net-ssh to version 3.0.1. Then you can write your config like

```
set :ssh_options, {
  user: "deploy",      
  keys: ["~/.ssh/id_rsa"]      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue for my application https://www.wiki11.com.

Those who are getting error

```
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@XXX.XX.XX.XXX
```

Here is the **solution**,

First of all you need to ssh to your server and run

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

and then

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and now change

```
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) } 
#...
```

to

```
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }
#...
```

I just removed `pub` from `id_rsa.pub`.

And then run

```
cap production deploy:initial
```

It should work now.